# Android - Duplicate Entry Error - How do I use one class from one JAR file when it exists in two JAR files without running into this error?

Tags: android, jar, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

How do I get my code to use only one class from one JAR file when the same class from two JAR files exist in the files ormlite-android-4.6.jar & ormlite-core-4.45.jar without running into this error?

Here is a copy of my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.engineering"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
//compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/butterknife-5.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar')
compile files('libs/com.springsource.org.junit-4.10.0.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/dagger-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/opencsv-3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.6.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar')
compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.16.jar')
compile files('libs/icepick-2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar')
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
   :app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

  > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl$1.class
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 5.131 secs

The code I think is trying to use BaseDaoImpl.class which both exists in package com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl in both ormlite-android-4.6.jar & ormlite-core-4.45.jar.  How do I get it to use one class from one JAR file without running into this error?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
   compile ("net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.0") {
        exclude group: 'org.joda.time'
    }
```

or to exclude module use

```
compile ("net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.0") {
    exclude module: 'jode-time'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run "gradlew dependencies" which will allow you to see all the libraries.  You can use the "exclude" directive to remove duplicate libraries.

Look here to read more about the exclude directive: https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies